# What's the difference between nvidia-smi Memory-Usage and GPU Memory Usage?

Tags: memory, gpu, nvidia

Running the `nvidia-smi` command displays for example:

[image]

What's the difference between `Memmory-Usage` and `GPU Memory Usage`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Memory-Usage` indicates:

```
used memory/total memory
```

Used memory is how much of the GPU's memory is in use.  Total Memory is how much is available, if nobody were using any of it.

`GPU Memory Usage` simply breaks this down by process.

This output apparently has one process running, and that process is using 10557 megabytes of GPU 0 memory.  That is essentially the same as the 10570 number reported above it.  Yes, there is a small difference, it is due to GPU memory consumption not associated with that process (e.g. in use by CUDA itself).

Comment: Thanks!  It's the small difference that I was really curious about.  That difference made me wonder if I was misinterpreting something.